# How do you test code that is run Immediately?

Tags: python, python-unittest

Using Python's Unittest framework how do you mock or replace a module that has code that is run as the module is loaded?

I understand this is poorly written code, but this is similar to what I have to test. (See example)

I understand that once a module is imported it can be patched to use mocks. But what if there is code that is run immediately?

I have a file that I need to put under test. One of the files it imports runs code immediately, see example.

file_under_test.py

```
from somewhere.something.worker import a_func as f

class ClassToTest():
    __init__(self):
...
```

the somewhere.something.worker module

```
import os
import redis
REDIS_HOST = os.environ.get('redishost', '') #<-- Mock this
connection = redis.Redis(host=REDIS_HOST) #<--- Mock this

class AClass():
    ...

def a_func():
    connection.doSomething()
    ...
```

Comment: I would consider the code to fail whatever test you had in mind, and require it to be refactored to avoid opening the connection immediately upon import. `a_func` should take the connection as an argument, or be a method of a class whose *instance* is given a connection.

Comment: At the very least, add an `init_connection()` function to the module to defer creating the connection until you are ready for the connection to take place.

Comment: @chepner that is what i was thinking too...re-write.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Defer creating the connection until you are really ready for it to happen. As a bonus, you can have `init_connection` take an optional pre-allocated connection rather than always creating it on-demand. This makes it easier to migrate towards avoiding the global connection altogether.

```
import os
import redis

connection = None

def init_connection(c=None):
    global connection
    if connection is None:
        if c is None:
            c = redis.Redis(host=os.environ.get('redishost', ''))
        connection = c

...
```

Then, in your test module, you can call `init_connection` from inside `setupModule`, with the option of passing in the desired connection-like object
instead of having to patch anything.

```
def setupModule():
    init_connection()
    # or
    # conn = Mock()
    # ... configure the mock ...
    # init_connection(conn)

class ClassToTest():
    __init__(self):
...
```

Comment: This is what I figured I would have to do. I was just wondering if there was another way :-(

Comment: Even if there *is* another way, I would still refactor.